# "What could X do besides Y?" or "What could X do, besides Y?"

Tags: grammar, sentence, commas

Example:

> But what can a tree do(,) besides turning carbon dioxide into oxygen?

Should I place a comma there? Why or why not?

Comment: That comma can make a whole lot of difference to the semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the two formulations are semantically equivalent, so on general principle I would omit the comma as superfluous with the following two exceptions:

1. Either subject *X* or clause *Y* is so wordy that the comma improves readability.
2. You want to encourage the reader to pause, as if to consider the question posed by the first clause before providing the answer in the second.